# How to create a vector using elements greater than x in another vector

Tags: r, vector

I created aVector containing 100 random values between 0 and 100. Now I need to create bVector by pulling whole elements from aVector that are >50. Can I use runif?

I've tried using runif placing aVector within the function but it's pulling fractioned numbers between 51 and 100.

```
set.seed
myVector <- sample(0:100, 100, replace=FALSE)
```

I expect to create 49 (can be random) numbers between 51 and 100 used to create my bVector. I do not need to use runif, but I'm new to R and would like more simple techniques.

Comment: r u looking for `sample(51:100)`?

Comment: Do you mean `sample(myVector[myVector >= 51])`?

Comment: `bVector <- myVector[myVector > 50]` will extract all elements > 50 into a new vector.

Comment: myVector[myVector > 50] is just what I needed. Thanks!